# Java: Errors in a Program?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, indexing

Write a program that reads a list of real numbers.  After the program ends it should print out only the unique numbers.  That is, only numbers that appear once in the list.  If there are more than 50 unique numbers on the list, then you should only print the first 50.
Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Hmwk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
    int n = 0;
    double[] numbersArray = new double[100000];
    while (input.hasNextDouble()){
        double in = input.nextDouble();
        numbersArray[n]=in;
        n++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(numbersArray);
    inList(numbersArray);
    double[] uniqueArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbersArray, 0, n);
    printReport(uniqueArray);
}


public static double[] inList(double[] list){
    int position = 0;
    final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
    double [] uniqueArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < list.length; j++){
            if (list[i] != list[j]){
                uniqueArray[position]= i;
                position++;
            }
            }
        }
    return uniqueArray;
    }



public static void printReport(double[] list)
{
    System.out.println("The unique numbers were");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

}


}
```

After creating a new algorithm and going through my book again I came up with the code above to do the problem explained at the top. I attempted to sort all of the numbers in the array that I brought in from input.txt. Then I attempted to compare the indexes of the numbers using inList. I tried to have it compare the index [0] to [1], [1] to [2], and so on. Being it a sorted list, if the numbers at the indexes being compared are equal, it is not a unique number to the list, but if they're different, they are a unique number and are added to uniqueArray. I get the following error when I run it however.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
at Hmwk.inList(Hmwk.java:33)
at Hmwk.main(Hmwk.java:20)
```

Any ideas for me? And like always, I truly appreciate your time.

Comment: `list` is an array of 50,000 elements, and you're looping from `0` to `list.length`, yet `uniqueArray` only holds 50 elements.  So yea, you're gonna hit an array index out of bounds.

Comment: How would I go about looping from [0] to the last double not 0.0 in my list?

Comment: So, if you have a list of 10,000 `3`'s followed up by distinct digits, should your program find all the distinct numbers?  Or, would it just return 3?  I'm unclear on this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `numbersArray` is defined with more elements than your `uniqueArray`:

```
double[] numbersArray = new double[100000];
```

and

```
final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
double [] uniqueArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
```

and

```
// list is in this case your numbersArray
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < list.length; j++){
        if (list[i] != list[j]){
            uniqueArray[position]= i;  // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this will crash, when position reaches 50, because your uniqueArray has only 50 elements starting with 0, so 49 is the last index here.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
uniqueArray[position]= i;
position++;
```

position is continuously incremented and hits 50.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a container class. HashMap with Double AS key and Integer as counter. Or a LinkedList of Double.